# Linq query with multiple counters

Tags: linq

I'm new to Linq and need some assistance. In fact I'm not even sure this is possible. Given the sample data:

```
WarehouseId     Sku     Dropship    QtyOrdered      QtyAvaliable
=================================================================
1               ABC-123                 1               6
2               ABC-123                 1               2
3               ABC-123                 1               0
1               XYZ-789                 2               11
2               XYZ-789                 2               1
3               XYZ-789                 2               3
1               JKL-456   Y             1               0
2               JKL-456   Y             1               0
3               JKL-456   Y             1               1
```

I'm trying to determine the total number of order items in stock for each warehouse, both for all order items and orders without dropship items. So the output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
WarehouseId: 1,
QtyInStock: 2,
QtyNonDropship: 2

WarehouseId: 2,
QtyInStock: 1,
QtyNonDropShip: 1

WarehouseId: 3,
QtyInStock: 2,
QtyNonDropship: 1
```

I've started a Linq query, but not sure how to do the counters. I'm pretty sure that I need a `GroupBy` somewhere.

```
var results = (from o in orderItems
                where o.QtySellable >= o.QtyOrdered // <-- add '1' to QtyInStock
                || (o.QtySellable >= o.QtyOrdered && o.Dropship != 'Y')// <-- add '1' to QtyNonDropShip
                select new 
                {
                    WarehouseId,
                    QtyInStock += QtyInStock 
                    QtyNonDropShip += QtyNonDropShip 
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you get those values: `WarehouseId: 1,
QtyInStock: 2, QtyNonDropship: 2` - you have total available quantity `6 + 11 + 0 = 17` and this value does not present in output. Also you are using field `QtySellable` in your query which does not exist in sample data

Comment: I'm not trying to count the number of available items in stock, I'm trying to count the items that are in stock. For example in the data set, there are 3 sku items and 3 warehouses. For each sku at each warehouse, check to see that the item is in stock. If `QtyOrdered >= QtyAvailable`, then add one to counter. That item is in stock.

Comment: For first warehouse there is only one item with `QtyOrdered >= QtyAvailable`. But in output you show `QtyInStock: 2`

Comment: Sorry, I miss typed that. It should be `QtyAvailable >= QtyOrdered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `WarehouseId`:

```
var results = from o in orderItems
              group o by o.WarehouseId into g
              select new { WarehouseId=g.Key,
                           QtyInStock=g.Count(e=>e.QtySellable >= e.QtyOrdered),
                           QtyNonDropShip =g.Count(e=>e.QtySellable >= e.QtyOrdered && e.Dropship != "Y")
                         };
```

Comment: That will give you `QtyInStock` equal to 3 for first warehouse. OP exects it to be 2